# Expanding to only first order in the functional minimisation derivation

Tags: variational-principle

Consider the functional minimisation derivation for $F[y, y'] = \int_a^b f(y, y')$.

This derivation begins by letting $y$ be our function which minimises $F$. We consider the variation in $F$, $\delta F$, due to a small deformation of our path $\delta y$. In particular, we have $\delta F = F[y + \delta y, y' + \delta y'] - F[y, y']$.

We expand $f$ to first order:

$f(y + \delta y, y' + \delta y') = f(y, y') + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \delta y + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} \delta y'$,

and then continue the derivation from there to find the Euler-Lagrange equation for $F$.

My question is about the expansion of $f$ to first order. It is surely the case that the $\delta y$ term in the expansion is much bigger than $\delta y^2$, since we have assumed that $\delta y$ is sufficiently small to allow us to do this. However, is it necessarily the case that the second order expansion term $\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \delta y^2$ is necessarily much less than the first order term $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} \delta y'$?

For instance, what if $\delta y$ had a particularly small derivative? How can we dump the first of these terms, but keep the second?

I don't think the motivation can be that we need a nonzero $\delta y$ and $\delta y'$ term somewhere in there. Given that $\int_a^b \delta y' = 0$, then if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$ is constant, the term $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} \delta y'$ integrates to zero, and so makes no change to the value of $F$. The term $\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y'^2} \delta y'^2$ could make a nonzero contribution to a change in $F$, but we insist it is 'small'. I'd say it's contribution is bigger than the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$ here, so why don't we keep it?

In my research, I saw [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/354112/why-is-that-in-the-action-principle-the-taylors-series-is-limited-to-the-first), but it was taking a more 'doesn't this propagate a lot of error?' approach, rather than specifically a 'sometimes the second order terms are bigger than the first?' approach.

Can anyone provide some insight? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach based on the Taylor expansion is quite non-rigorous, but it can be replaced with a natural approach based on standard derivatives which yields exactly the same final result.

Consider the functional $F[y] := \int_a^bf(y(t),y'(t))dt$ where  the $C^2$ curves $y$ are constrained to satisfy the boundary conditions $y(a) =y_a$, $y(b)=y_b$ for some constants $y_a,y_b$.

*We say that a function $y_0$ is an extremal curve of $F$ if for every deformation $y_0(t) + \alpha \delta y(t)$ with $\delta y$ any curve with  $\delta y(a)=\delta y(b)=0$ (in order to satisfy the boundary conditions)   and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, it holds*
$$\frac{d}{d\alpha}|_{\alpha=0} F[y_0+\alpha \delta y]=0\:.\tag{1}$$

The reason for this maybe apparently cumbersome definition relies upon the analogous fact in standard calculus: if $f=f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then  $x_0$ is an extremal point if and only if $$\frac{d}{d\alpha}|_{\alpha =0} f(x_0 + \alpha \delta x)=0 \quad \mbox{for every $\delta x \in \mathbb{R}^n$}\tag{2}$$
In fact, (2) is equivalent to 
$$\delta x \cdot \nabla f(x_0)=0 \quad \mbox{for every $\eta \in \mathbb{R}^n$}$$
which means, because $\delta x$ is arbitrary,
$$\nabla f(x_0)=0$$
which is nothing but the standard definition of extremal point $x_0$ for the function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

Coming back to (1), if $F(y) = \int_a^b f(y(t),y'(t))dt$, the equation can be rephrased to
$$\frac{d}{d\alpha}|_{\alpha=0}\int_a^b f(y_0+ \alpha \delta y, y_0' + \alpha \delta y') dt=0,$$
that is
$$ \int_a^b \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{y_0, y_0'} \delta y + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}|_{y_0,y'_0} \delta y' dt=0\:.\tag{3}$$
Using $\delta y(a)=\delta y(b)=0$ and integration by parts, (3) can be equivalently written
$$ \int_a^b \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{y_0,y'_0}- \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}|_{y_0,y'_0}\right)\:\delta y(t) \: dt =0$$
The arbitrariness of $\delta y$ (and the fact that its factor is continuous) implies the usual E-L equations for $y_0$.

I stress that

(1) nowhere $\delta y$ is required to be small,

(2) all mathematical passages are justified just assuming the integrand function  $f$ to be sufficiently regular ($C^2$ is sufficient with $-\infty < a < b < +\infty$),

(3) everyting arises from (is equivalent to) the definition (1) of extremal curve,

(4) this approach, with some technical hypotheses leads to the definition of the *Gateaux derivative* of functionals in functional analysis.