# Why do we discount higher-order variations when applying variational methods in analytical mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, approximations, variational-calculus

In [*No-Nonsense Classical Mechanics*](https://nononsensebooks.com/cm/), the calculus of variations is introduced with what I'm sure is a standard example. We try to find the minima of function $f(x) = x^2$ by evaluating it at $x + \epsilon$. At the minimum point, all terms that include $\epsilon$ in first-order must vanish. This makes sense because $f$ must increase when travelling away from the minimum in any direction. If there was a first-order $\epsilon$ term, you would simply have to go in $-\epsilon$ and the function would decrease, making the original point no longer a minimum. Quadratic (and other even) terms can remain because they will only increase $f$ for any value of $\epsilon$. Furthermore, as $\epsilon << 1$, any decrease in $f$ caused by the linear term cannot be offset by an increase of any (much smaller) higher-order terms.

All of this so far makes sense to me. However, the book explicitly discounts all higher-order terms without further explanation. I do not understand why we allow odd higher-order terms in $\epsilon$ to remain. All else equal, a decrease in $\epsilon$ will cause an odd power term to decrease, thereby decreasing $f$ from its supposed minimum. The book does state that there is some "real reason" behind requiring that the linear terms vanish, which is discussed in a later chapter. However, I am sure there must be some mathematical justification.

The only possible explanation I came up with is that, since $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal, its higher-order powers are so small as to be indistinguishable from zero, and so we truly can neglect them. The main reason I even thought of this was because of 3Blue1Brown's video "deriving" the power rule, where he throws away some squares of infinitesimals as negligible. I asked my E&M professor and he said that focusing on the linear terms is analogous to taking the first-order term in a Taylor series: just a convenient approximation. In that view, the Euler-Lagrange Equation, Hamilton's Equations, and all other results of analytical mechanics are but approximations even in the classical domain.

So what's really going on here? And if this does actually amount to a first-order approximation, what does higher-order analytical mechanics look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is that in the action principle, the Taylor's series is limited to the first order?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/354112/)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, good answer! Now I understand why too. -NN

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, I'll be honest it doesn't. It says the exact same thing as my book, which is that an extremum is characterized by a first-order variation. It doesn't explain why or address my comment about odd higher-order terms.

Comment: @AryanPrasad When you look for a max or a min, do you care about the 2nd derivative?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero We don't, but I still don't see how that takes care of my concern about odd higher-order variational terms. If they exist, then there must be a direction we can move in which those terms decrease.

Comment: that's not what variational calculus does.  It only looks for the *extremum* of the integral, not the integral itself (or an approximation to the integral).  As a result, only the first derivatives in the argument of the integral enter, because extrema are determined by first derivatives.  There's a nice chapter on calculus of variation in *Mary L Boas, Mathematical methods in the physical sciences*, which I highly recommend.  Again, it's not about evaluating a function or the integral of a function, but about finding the extremum, for which only the first derivative is required.